# What are monte carlo optimization techniques used in machine learning?

Tags: sampling, optimization, deep-learning

Normally in machine learning we use derivatives in-order to optimize a cost function . But I saw monte carlo optimization method which uses integrals in-order to optimize specially in reinforcement learning problems and some sampling problems ?

What is the difference of these two types ?

Comment: monte carlo *optimization* will use random numbers to either randomly explore a function, or to approximate the objective function. monte carlo *integration* uses samples to approximate expectations.

Comment: Can in elborate it more with an example where we need to use mote carlo methods instead derivative based optimization methods like SGD , LBFGS . 

What do you mean by random exploration of a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derivatives and Monte-Carlo techniques are not used in the same way for optimization.

If a cost function is easy to compute we can use derivatives to perform a gradient descent method of optimizing parameters.

If a cost function is expensive to compute then it might not be feasible to calculate the derivatives. In these cases we must be careful with how many times we compute the cost function, we need an efficient method of optimizing the parameters for the cost function.

A Monte-Carlo approach is used for estimation, not for optimization. However, estimation is helpful for producing an efficient optimization algorithm. If the cost function is expensive to compute then we can use Monte-Carlo methods to estimate it with much less computing time.

Comment: So we use mote carlo methods to get rid of expensive cost functions. Because if we use some kind of iterative method like SGD on an expensive cost function it is too hard to optimize.  Am I write ?




SGD uses derivatives to compute the gradients . What about Monte Carlo method ? What is it using to estimate , integrals ?

Comment: @ShamaneSiriwardhana yes you're right, SGD with a mini-batch is a randomized method. We calculate the gradient for a few random samples instead of all samples (the exact gradient)

Comment: Can you give an example of a cost function that is difficult to compute and requires MC?

Comment: Yes! Please can you help to understand this with comparing two cost functions? 
I'v read that early days when using softmax with cross entropy loss function in  language models they have use MC get rid of the expensive summation. (Can be equal to number of vocabulary size) . 

Can You give an example .